# How do you add an image to a website hyperlink

Tags: html, hyperlink, sms

When sending a website hyperlink via SMS text message on my Android, I noticed some websites have a preview image above the title name, domain description, and url. I found this wasn't just video platforms but also blog articles, etc. Picture examples listed below.

When checking to see if this question has been asked prior, it was either confused for or convoluted with basic html requests asking how to add a hyper link to a photo. So please understand that this isn't a request for that.

I'm guessing it's a head meta tag data. Could someone share the code line and where it's placement in the .html file is. Is there an optimal size/ resolution as well? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 3 days active and 13 views with zero replies I decided to aggressively comb high end website's source code until I found the answer.

How I found it: F12 and ctrl+F while searching "src" was a bust but "img" was the ticket to finding this line!

```
<meta property="og:image" content="x.jpg" name="image">
```

This lead me to finding "Open Graph Protocol" originally developed by Facebook.
You can read more about the concept here https://ogp.me/

or listen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QwEQKM4YRnU&t=59s

It's pretty straight forward with this information and ends my question. Happy coding, future readers!